# How to use passed variable in a PDO prepared SELECT WHERE statement

Tags: php, variables, pdo

I am trying to figure out how to use a php variable in a PDO prepared statement.  The code below returns nothing.  The part that I'm not sure about is

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM laptop WHERE '$ckey' = :avalue");
```

I'm trying to use a variable for the key and the value,  It doesn't seem to be returning results.  The switch statement is meant to look for which field the user filled out.  This is a basic search for a rudimentary inventory system.  I know there are open source solutions available, but my company won't let us use open source software on the network.  I also realize the output isn't formatted into a table, but I figured I'd get the query to work, then worry about prettying up the output.  I also realize there are some similar questions, but I haven't seen anyone trying to use variables in the WHERE part of a statement.  If it's because it won't work, and everyone knows this but me, I apologize.

Here is the entire code block.

```
    function mkquery($ckey,$cdata)
{


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    }

                catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }


   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM laptop WHERE '$ckey' = :avalue"); 
 //$stmt is the prepared query, you execute it to perform the query
   $stmt->bindParam(':avalue',$ckey, PDO::PARAM_STR);             
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();  
                foreach($result as $val ) {

                                echo $val['Model'] . " ";
                                echo $val['Name'] . " ";
                                echo $val['DellTag'] . " ";
                                echo $val['HHSCTag'] . " ";
                                echo $val['OS'] . " ";
                                echo $val['KBOX'] . " ";
                                echo $val['SB'] . " ";
                                echo $val['Issued'] . " ";
                                echo $val['Tech'] . " ";
                                echo "<br>";

    }
}

switch (isset($_POST))  {

case isset($_POST['name']):
                $selector = 'name';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['name']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['model']):
                $selector = 'model';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['model']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['delltag']):
                $selector = 'delltag';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['delltag']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['hhsctag']):
                $selector = 'hhsctag';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['hhsctag']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['city']):
                $selector = 'city';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['city']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['kbox']):
                $selector = 'kbox';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['kbox']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['sb']):
                $selector = 'sb';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['sb']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['issued']):
                $selector = 'issued';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['issued']);
                break;

case isset($_POST['tech']):
                $selector = 'tech';
                mkquery($selector,$_POST['tech']);
                break;

default: 
                echo 'No input on form detected';
                break;

                                                                                                }

                                                                         a                                       


$conn = null;
```

Comment: The whole point of prepared statements is so you don't have to use variables in your query strings. RTM, `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field = :bind_key');` to get the `PDOStatement` instance, then: `$stmt->execute([':bind_key' => $valueInWhere]);`. To get the results `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: `'$ckey'` is the column? If so it should be in backticks. It is confusing that you are comparing `'$ckey'` against the bound `$ckey`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm from a c++ background, with a good decade of rust, and I'm used to passing by value.  I just want to take post data and use it to generate a search result type query.

Comment: Still not clear what is what. Also use the `@` to tag users, no one gets notified of updates without that. Is `$ckey` suppose to be the column name or the value you are searching for?